# How to downgrade flutter version for only one project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the latest flutter version 3.3.3
But my one app is on 2.5.3. I don't want to upgrade it to the latest version because it will take time. I just want my flutter SDK to downgrade to 2.5.3 but only for that project not for the entire machine. If we want to downgrade flutter version we simply write

`flutter downgrade v2.5.3`

But I only want to downgrade for that project.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you could install multiple versions of the Flutter SDK and just run the corresponding copy of `bin/flutter` for the version you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the FVM package.

https://fvm.app/